# Dynamic resource access inner property

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following Dynamic Resource:

```
public class Foo
{
     public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

I set my resource using:

```
Application.Current.Resources["Foo"] = myFoo;
```

But when I try to access my bar property it does not work:

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource Foo.bar}" />
```

However using this approach works:

```
<Image BindingContext="{DynamicResource Foo}" Source="{Binding bar}" />
```

The problem is that the approach above can not be used when I can´t override my Binding. My question is, How can I access inner properties of a DynamicResource without override the BindingContext ?

Comment: If Foo was static you could use: {x:Static local:Foo.Bar}